# Remove or Set Padding in ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart, padding

I'm completely new to Flutter / Dart so pls excuse if this is a noob question.
I'm trying to remove the space on top and bottom of the Text of a ListTile element from the "first app" example code.
[So basically the two areas with the red pointers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUnUS.png)

The code looks like

```
  return ListTile(
    //dense: true,
    //minVerticalPadding: 1.0,
    //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
    tileColor: Colors.blue,
    title: Text(
      pair.asPascalCase,
      style: _biggerFont,
    ),
  );
```

As u can see, I tried dense, minVerticalPadding and contentPadding, but none of them did the job.

Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `VisualDensity` property to set minimum padding around Your `ListTile`.
that value can't lower than -4 and upper than +4:

```
ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      dense: true,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
      title: Text("hello"),
    )
```

and if you want to keep your horizontal padding you can use this code:

```
ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
      dense: true,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
      title: Text("hello"),
    )
```

Comment: This helped, though padding is just less and not gone.

Comment: yes. in listTile you can't set padding to zero. if you want achiev that aim you should use another widget

Comment: or you can create your custom widget.

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
ListTile(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    tileColor: Colors.blue,
    title: Text(
       "hello"
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer. Tried it before and again. It does change the padding to the left, but unfortunately not top and bottom :(

Comment: i have edited my answer. try using visualDensity